# Odd-length string error with binascii.unhexlify

Tags: python-2.7, binary, binascii

I'm trying to convert back and forth an ASCII string to its binary representation as follows.

```
s=chr(0)*15 + chr(0x01)
bst = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(s), 16))
n = int(bst, 2)
binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n)
```

However, I get the following error at the end which doesn't make much sense to me.

> 1 binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n)
>
> TypeError: Odd-length string

What's the issue and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the python console:

```
>>> help(binascii.unhexlify)

unhexlify(...)
    a2b_hex(hexstr) -> s; Binary data of hexadecimal representation.

    hexstr must contain an even number of hex digits (upper or lower case).
    This function is also available as "unhexlify()"
```

So the error is consistent. What you have to do is padding with `'0'` to have an even number:

```
>>> binascii.unhexlify('0%x' % n)
'\x01'
```

Comment: Padding at the beginning or at the end?

Answer (score -1):

```
                n = int(wer, 2)

                qqwslenf=len(wer)
                qqwslenf=(qqwslenf/8)*2
                qqwslenf=str(qqwslenf)
                qqwslenf="%0"+qqwslenf+"x"


                jlz=binascii.unhexlify(qqwslenf % n)
                #we convert from binary to ASCII exactly size of need by half bytes.
```